# No Move to SD Card or Move to USB option in android 4.2.2

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, installation

I have a Carbonn Phone (model: A18+)

http://www.karbonnmobiles.com/karbonn-A18+-proid-193.html

Android Version is 4.2.2

Under Settings -> Storage -> 'Preferred install location' and it has three options for it:

1. Internal device storage
2. Phone storage
3. Let the system decide

there is no option for "External storage device"

but below Preferred install location there is another option: Settings -> Storage -> "Default Write Disk" and it has two options:

1. Phone storage
2. SD Card

I have "SD Card" selected here

But I don't have choice to choose SD Card or External storage to install apps and when I install any app from 'play store' that goes to either to phone or to internal storage.
Even after going to the Settings -> Apps ->

I only see 4 tabs

Downloaded | Phone Storage | Running | All

there is no 'SD Card' or 'USB Storage' tab and when i tap any app here it only shows "Move to Phone storage" or "Move to Internal Storage" on 'App Info' Screen.

My question is How can I move or install apps to External SD Card. I have tried many apps like APP2SD or similar ones. But no app gives me to move apps to SD Card. Even I have tried rooting my phone, that also doesn't work.

Comment: That limitation has been forced upon you by the "ROM baker" (most likely the manufacturer). LG support e.g. falsely claims "Android 4.x doesn't support it anymore", which of course is not true. For possible solutions, please take a look at: [Installing to SDCard by default](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/43517/16575) / [Android Devices: use external storage as a default storage](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/50252/16575) / our [app2sd tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/app2sd/info).