# Set Android device default install location to external SD card

Tags: installation, sd-card, geolocation

I have Samsung GalaxyS2. Is there a way to set the default install location to SD card of all downloaded apps from play store.

Comment: Check if your phone has that ability to move the Apps to SD card instead of rooting it. Otherwise, you can move the apps that have been installed on your phone to SD card as follows!

Open the Application Manager.

You’ll find it under the More tab in Settings.

Inside the Application Manager, swipe to the left once to view a list of all the apps that you can move to the card.

Comment: Yes, my phone has such capability. I want by default all apps that are going to be installed to be put on the SD card. Without me moving them manual after they are installed. Thanks.

Comment: Not sure why the link i posted did not appear. Here is the link that may help you `http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/50252/android-devices-use-external-storage-as-a-default-storage`

Answer (score 0):

This has been by far one the best utility app that I have bought for my phone. It will install to your SD card and can be set to do so by default:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.buak.Link2SD&hl=en

I had a special condition where my SD card was "emulated" and so the OS couldn't link the app to the external storage. This app solves that by having you partition the SD card and then using a startup script to mount it as another ext filesystem that it can use to link to. It does this all fairly automatic and seamless.

Disclaimer: I am not affiliated or know the developer of this app, I just shopped around and found this to be the best one under all circumstances.

(you may need to be rooted, not sure for your device)

Comment: Hi, this [article](http://www.fixedbyvonnie.com/2014/06/install-android-apps-sd-card-default/#.VGxLK4uUfhk) has helped me.