# Make my external SD card as my internal memory for apps

Tags: applications, external-sd, insufficient-memory

I have a CUBOT P7 phone with very little internal memory, so I installed an 8GB external SD card.

However, my apps will not download directly to there, and I have no more space on my internal memory.

How do I modify my phone so that apps download directly to my SD card? with out having to root my phone

Comment: You can't make them download to the SD card, you have to have enough space on the internal storage for that.  You can have them install to the SD by default, though.  Free up some space or move some existing apps to the SD card.

Answer (score 1):

It seems this problem have been issued by other member in this thread:

[Android Devices: use external storage as a default storage](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/50252/android-devices-use-external-storage-as-a-default-storage)

I'm following the steps myself, as I have the same problem.